Change stack values in R based on the first time a pixel has a certain value in R
I am working in R with terra library. I have a SpatRaster of 21 layers with values 0 and 1.
This is my SpatRaster object
> mascara1_t
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 628, 865, 21  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.0001796631, 0.0001796631  (x, y)
extent      : -0.5923491, -0.4369406, 39.93461, 40.04743  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source(s)   : memory
names       : lyr1, lyr2, lyr3, lyr4, lyr5, lyr6, ... 
min values  :    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0, ... 
max values  :    1,    1,    1,    1,    1,    1, ... 

I want to create a new SpatRaster object meeting this criteria. The first time a pixel is 0, then, the value change to 0 in the following bands. Lets say for instance a pixel has values of 1 and then for the fifth band the value changed to 0. Then I would like to have value 0 for the rest of bands. How can I do this in R? This is my code so far. Thanks in advance!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
